# How do I send a data-only Android notification using the Android SDK?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-push-notification

Using Firebase Cloud Messaging I can [push data-only messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options). Doing this sends data to my app without showing a notification to the user. Is there any way to do this using only the Android SDK?

Comment: "Is there any way to do this using only the Android SDK?" -- could you explain a bit more what you are looking to do? For example, are you trying to have an Android client communicate with a server?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to show a notification to the user when your app receives data.
You can manually create a notification in your customized `FirebaseMessagingService`.

According to the [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive?hl=en), Data-only messages are forwarded to your customized `FirebaseMessagingService` whether your app is foreground or background.

So what you have to do is manually create a notification by using `Notification.Builder` and `NotificationManager` in `onMessageReceived` of your customized `FirebaseMessagingService`.
You can check the sample code [here](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/a5b7968230d3d256182b3b9f50a01df626a11a7b/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/example/messaging/kotlin/MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt#L89-L124).